# Accepting bitcoin during crowdsale and making refund if soft cap not reached

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ico, crowdsale, bitcoin

I'm gonna make some api to allow my crowdsale to accept bitcoin, however I ran into a problem.  Because I will make refunds if soft cap not reached. What the best way to refund everything that was bought with btc?

Comment: Make a button "Pay with Bitcoin" and make it a link to a this article https://tokenmarket.net/what-is/how-to-participate-in-ethereum-token-sale-and-pay-with-bitcoin/

Answer (score 0):

There is no choice but to do it "manually".

You can code a robot that will send back all the transactions to adresses that partipated in the crowdsale